# query conversion is giving can not convert error in linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT [t0].[ID]
FROM [dbo].[test] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[CID] = 'abc'
and ([t0].[ID] IN (Select RID from master where CID='abc'))
ORDER BY [t0].[ID]
```

Is my query, I have written a Linq_to_sql query for the same . but its throwing me the error.

My Linq query.

```
Var IdList=db.Master.where(a=>a.CID=="abc").select(p=>new{p.RID}).toList();

var _List =db.test.where(a=>a.CID=="abc" && a.contains(IdList)).OrderBy(s => s.ID).ToList()
```

Why its throwing  the error?

```
can not convert from 'system.collection.Generic.List<<anonymous type:string RID>>'to 'string'
```

Comment: please post your error

Comment: can not convert from  'system.collection.Generic.List<<anonymous type:string RID>>'to 'string

Comment: This is wrong : a.contains(IdList)  'a' is a single string  I think you want IdList.Contains()

Comment: `IdList.Contains(a.ID)`

Comment: @Serg , that too giving an error "can not convert from  string to '<anonymous type:string RID>"

Comment: Try `.select(p=>p.RID )` .

Comment: @serg . you are correct. we should not use  new in this case. Bravo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we've got it )

```
Var IdList=db.Master.where(a=>a.CID=="abc").select(p=>p.RID).toList();

var _List =db.test.where(a=>a.CID=="abc" && IdList.contains(a.ID)).OrderBy(s => s.ID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to write new in select if you are fetching only one column,
and also you have to use contains method to check that id present in that above query of id's.

var ridList = db.master.where(x=>x.cid === 'abc').select(x=>x.rid).tolist();

db.test.where(x=>x.cid==='abc' && ridList.contains(x.id).OrderBy(s => s.ID).tolist();